# Python Selenium with chromedriver wait some seconds for multiple Url

Tags: python, selenium

I am using this scripts for scrape multiple URLS.
I want it to wait 3 seconds when switching from url to url.is this possible?

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv

oranev = r"^(?!.*Handikaplı).*^(?!.*Yarı).*^(?!.*Alt).*Maç Sonucu.*$[\s\S]*?>1<[\s\S]*?[\>](-|\d\d*\.\d\d|\d\d*)"
oranX = r"^(?!.*Handikaplı).*^(?!.*Yarı).*^(?!.*Alt).*Maç Sonucu.*$[\s\S]*?>X<[\s\S]*?[\>](-|\d\d*\.\d\d|\d\d*)"
orandep = r"^(?!.*Handikaplı).*^(?!.*Yarı).*^(?!.*Alt).*Maç Sonucu.*$[\s\S]*?>2<[\s\S]*?[\>](-|\d\d*\.\d\d|\d\d*)"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
URLs =['http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Mac/3495245/Boca-Juniors-Santos",http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Mac/3482298/Aris-Saloniki-Volos-NFC']

file = open('oranlar.csv', 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['Ev', 'X', 'Dep'])

for link in URLs:
  driver.get(link)

  html_source = driver.page_source    
  oranevoran = re.search(oranev, html_source, re.MULTILINE)
  oranxoran = re.search(oranX, html_source, re.MULTILINE)
  orandeporan = re.search(orandep, html_source, re.MULTILINE)
  print(oranevoran.group(1))
  print(oranxoran.group(1))
  print(orandeporan.group(1))
  writer.writerow([oranevoran.group(1), oranxoran.group(1), 
  orandeporan.group(1)])

driver.quit()
```

I used these options but not success

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.implicitly_wait(90)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.set_script_timeout(30)
```

Comment: [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) only take place when the item you're looking for is not loaded. If you need to wait regardless the page is loaded, you can use `time.sleep(3)` in your main thread.

Comment: This is only for first time start for chrome driver.is it right?But i want wait 3 seconds for every continuous link.Maybe i can't understand.how can i use time.sleep(3) for every link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you should do it like they have done on  [Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python) and imported the WebDriverWait and called it explicitly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/about_careers.htm")
#  presence_of_element_located expected condition wait for 8 seconds
try:
    w = WebDriverWait(driver, 8)
    w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h1")))
    print("Page load happened")

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout happened no page load")
driver.close()
```

If you don't care about whether the URL has loaded you can always use the time.sleep function

```
import time

time.sleep(random.uniform(3,4))
```